# How to make LyX create a new file from template on the command line?

Tags: lyx

Is there a command (for the Linux or Windows command line) that tells LyX to create a new file from a template that I specify as argument of the command? I would like to create a new file from a template without first starting LyX and then clicking `File ▹ New from template`. My goal is to have a desktop icon for some template X that I can double-click to start LyX with the template X loaded as a new document.

Comment: Maybe is possible with the `-batch` option (run `man lyx`) but some like `cp  /usr/share/lyx/template/letter-lyx x.lyx  &&  lyx x.lyx`   never fails.

Comment: I like Fran's idea. In LyX 2.4.0 (probably not released for a while), it will be possible to do the following: `lyx --execute 'buffer-new-template newfile /usr/local/share/lyx/templates/Letters/Letter_%28Standard_Class%29.lyx'`, but Fran's idea is simple and should work for 2.3.x as well.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? If Ubuntu, then when you create a new file in a folder using Nautilus, you can choose from a set of templates to which you can add your own (ad the template file to the ~/Templates folder) . I have a few LyX file types there.